# Akka stream equivalent of flatmap operator in RxJava

Tags: akka, rx-java, akka-stream

I have a background in RxJava and now I am getting started using Akka Streams.
When I need to compose a stream with the result of the first stream in RxJava, I usually do the following:

```
val fooBarObserable = fooObservable.flatmap { foo ->
   return barObservable.map { bar -> someOperation (foo, bar) }
}
```

In this example, `fooObservable`emits `Foo` type, `barObservable` emits `Bar` type and fooBarObserable emits `FooBar` type.

obs:

1. Observable is very similar to `Source` in Akka Streams.
2. barObservable will be a Flow

So what's the easy way to compose a stream like that in Akka?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `flatMapConcat`, as follows :

```
  final case class Foo(a: String)
  final case class Bar(a: String)

  val fooSource = Source(List(Foo("q-foo"), Foo("b-foo"), Foo("d-foo")))
  val barSource = Source(List(Bar("q-bar"), Bar("b-bar"), Bar("d-bar")))

  private val value: Source[String, NotUsed] = fooSource.flatMapConcat(foo => {
    barSource.map(bar => {
      foo.a + bar.a
    })
  })
```

Running this : `value.runWith(Sink.foreach(println))` will yield :

```
q-foo q-bar
q-foo b-bar
q-foo d-bar
b-foo q-bar
b-foo b-bar
b-foo d-bar
d-foo q-bar
d-foo b-bar
d-foo d-bar
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if barSource is a Flow and not a Source?

Comment: can you specify the type of the flow ? is it `Flow[Bar, Bar, NotUsed]` ?

Comment: Yep! it's it Flow[Bar, Bar, NotUsed]

Comment: okay, then we can't use `fooSource.via(barFlow)` because the type are incompatible (fooSource giving `Foos` and `barFlow` is a flow for `Bar` Type),  we will need to find another solution

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I'm not quite familiar with the RxJava so I may misunderstand what semantics it is you are after.

As a flow is not terminated you couldn't really combine its output with a source in the style of `fooSource.operation(barFlow)` as that wouldn't give you a reasonable graph of stages back - you'd first need to provide a `barSource` and combine the `barFlow` with that.

You could compose it the other way around though, for example like this:

```scala
val barFlow: Flow[Bar, Bar, NotUsed] = ???
val fooSource: Source[Foo, NotUsed] = ???

val fooToBarFooPairsFlow: Flow[Bar, (Bar, Foo), NotUsed] =
  barFlow.zip(fooSource)
```

Which would tuple up pairs of values of foo and bar let you later run it with a `barSource.via(fooToBarFooPairsFlow).map { case (bar, foo) => op(bar, foo) }`

Comment: zip required that Bar and Flow emit items and Bar only emit items after Foo.

Comment: As I said, not quite familiar with the semantics of RxJava, wouldn't the `someOperation(foo, bar)` also require an element from each observable? Will it invoke `someOperation` several times with the same (latest) `foo` for every `bar` that comes in?